# Question about Leonard Gillman's proof of the divergence of the Harmonic series.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, geometry, proof-explanation

Leonard Gillman (1917 – 2009) was an American mathematician, emeritus professor at the University of Texas, Austin. His proof of the divergence of the Harmonic series appeared in *The College Mathematics Journal*(March 2002) which you can read it [here](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/archives/physics116A10/harmapa.pdf). Page: 5/13

My problem is that I have hard time understanding the conclusion of the proof, especially the contradiction part.It will be great if somebody helps me understand it. Thank you:)

Comment: Can you be more specific? How we conclude $S > S$? Or why that's a contradiction? Or ... ?

Comment: I need some help understanding the contradiction part.

Comment: The contradiction is $S \gt S$

Comment: With a bit of handwaving, you could see this as saying that $S=S+\log_e(2)$, which is not true for any finite $S$ but might be true if $S=\infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a proof by contradiction.

It starts by supposing $S=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots$ converges to a finite sum (it would then be absolutely convergent since all terms are positive)

and then notes that this is strictly greater than $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots$ by making fractions with odd denominators smaller (in fact the difference would be $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{30}+\cdots$)

and then inserts some brackets $(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2})+(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4})+(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6})+\cdots$ which would give $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots$ and this is $S$ again.

So if $S$ converges to a finite sum then $S \gt S$ strictly.  This is a contradiction given that in fact $S=S$, implying that $S$ does not have a finite sum

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that the series converges, because it is a series of positive terms, it converges absolutely. So if you reorder, you should get that same $S$. But the argument in the proof shows a reordering that allows you to argue that the number $S$ satisfies $S>S$. As this is impossible, such number cannot exist and the series does not converge.

Comment: There is no reordering, just regrouping.